# Justify html page length

Tags: html, css

I have one django project. In the html template, the page length may not be constant since it may be longer if more inputs to give.

I may need to justify the length of the page to show the footer.

I try to use the `relative` *position* style for the footer, but it may not show well since if too little information may lift up the footer so high.

Hence, I may need to adjust the footer position due to the length of the page.

How could justify such length? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly: [Take a look](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-keep-your-footer-where-it-belongs-59c6aa05c59c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative position is refered to the parent element. Then, in that case, you must use the absolute, to bring it always at the bottom, independentment of the height of the body or parent.

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Then, its going to be better if you define a height, otherwise the footer will be on top of the page content. Then:

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px // for exemple
}

.page-content {// or body
  padding-bottom: 200px // height of the footer
}
```

Hope it helped.